# Django extra javascript is not working in the child page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a very basic base and child page style implementation. 
My goal is to show an alert written in javascript, when i click the button in the `child.html`. The problem is that when i try to use `extra_js` in the child page, the javascript code does not work in the child page. However, the same js block runs when it is moved to `base.html`. Did i miss something, why `extra_ javascript` code is not working in the child page?

**base.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>{% block title %}My amazing site{% endblock %}</title>
</head>


{% comment %} 
When I enable these lines, it works.Why??? it does not work in the child page???
   <script>
    function myfunction2(){
        alert("The button is clicked in child page!");
    }
</script>{% endcomment %}
    <body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        {% block sidebar %}
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/blog/">Blog</a></li>
            </ul>
        {% endblock %}
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**child.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block extra_css %}
    <style type="text/css">

        #mydiv{
            height: 50px;
            width:200px;
            margin-top:5px;
            border:2px solid;
        }

    </style>
{% endblock %}

{% block extra_js %}
    <script>
    function myfunction2(){
    alert("The button is clicked in child page!");
    }
    </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

    <h2>Child page</h2>

    <div id="mydiv">
    <p>
        Some text goes here...
    </p>
    </div>

    <input type="submit"  class="field button"  style="float: left; " name="submit"  value="Submit" id="Submit1" onclick ="myfunction2();"> </input>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to define an empty `{% block extra_js %}` in the `base.html`, then Django is placing the content of the block `extra_js` of the`child.html` and place it in the block of the parent.

`base.html` should look something like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
...
<div id="content">
{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
</div>

{% block extra_js %}{% endblock extra_js %}
</body>
</html>
```